# OuthShare Kit shares once in linkedin

Tags: objective-c

OuthShare Kit shares one/day in linkedin.But I need to share continuously in linkedin for the single user.

Answer (score 0):

change these lines in post update function
 you can share more than once..............

```
 NSDictionary *update = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"sharing text", @"comment",
                            [[NSDictionary alloc] 
                             initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"nwme project",@"title",@"any title",@"submitted-url",@"image url",@"submitted-image-url",nil], @"content",
                            [[NSDictionary alloc] 
                             initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"anyone",@"code",nil],@"visibility",nil];
```